# How to enable Emmet in Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code for Mac, and I want to use Emmet. I can't seem to figure out where to enable the 'tab' functionality. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).
2. Search for setting id `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab` and enable it.

Comment: Am I missing an option? I can't seem to find Code > Preferences > Settings

Comment: It should be at the very top menu (hidden if in fullscreen mode). You can use the keyboard shortcut (Mac: `⌘,`). https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf

Comment: I'm either REALLY blind or just really dumb, but I've gone through ever menu option in preferences and I can't find the settings.json file. `⌘,` opens the Preference pane, and in my pane I can't find settings. I feel super dumb, but Thank god for y'all.

Comment: hit F1, then you'll see a drop down menu, type 'open settings' on top and choose the highlighted item.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Apparently I have a broken version of Visual Studio or I'm just way dumb... When I press F1 nothing happens. Not sure if I'm the only one with this issue, but I've done my due diligence to Google the answer and scour the forums and found no one else with this issue.

Comment: Actually, I just realized you tagged this question with both Visual Studio AND Visual Studio Code. They're both completely different programs and it sounds like you're using Visual Studio, which means my answer and the docs I linked you to are not relevant.

Comment: Well that would explain my problems! I didn't realize there was a difference. So the answer to my problem was I was just being dumb. Thanks for bearing with me and being so helpful!

Comment: Eh, just a bad choice of branding on Microsoft's part. Most people don't know there's a difference when they first come across VS Code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Visual Studio Code 0.10.1 or higher
2. List item Launch VS Code Launch the command palette by using Ctrl-Shift-P (Windows, Linux) or Cmd-Shift-P (OSX)
3. List item Type HTML5 Boilerplate Button click "Edit in setting.json
4. List item Append following code:
   "emmet.includeLanguages": {
   "javascript": "javascriptreact",
   "razor": "html",
   "plaintext": "pug"
   }
5. List item Reload Visual Studio Code

Answer (score -2):

I have faced this issue in visual studio and resolved it.

if it's disabled enable it by going to preferences

if you are trying to code some html on visual studio and want to ide to help you use boilerplate

try below steps https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate

if it worked : "cheers .!"

else:

it could be issue with select language mode. on the bottom of Visual studio next to indents select language mode and change it to html or desired.

Thanks & Regards,
Surya kiran.